# C++ nested structs' typedefs (metaclass) compilation error

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

I want to create nested templated structure typedef's to create something of a metaclass with metamethods, that can have different arguments. Sample code is following:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <int one, int two, int three>
struct vector_c{
    enum{
    v1 = one,
    v2 = two,
    v3 = three
    };

    template <typename vector>
    struct sum{
        typedef vector_c<
            one+vector::v1,
            two+vector::v2,
            three+vector::v3
        > type;
    };
};


int main() {
    vector_c<1,2,3>::sum<vector_c<3,2,1>>::type asdf;
    return 0;
}
```

This gives me following error:

> prog.cpp:24: error: '::type' has not been declared prog.cpp:24: error:
>   template argument 3 is invalid prog.cpp:24: error: template argument 1
>   is invalid

Example can be found in here:

https://ideone.com/9BQ2FI

How can I achieve my goal? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work in C++11, it looks like you tried this with a pretty old compiler.

```
vector_c<1,2,3>::sum<vector_c<3,2,1>>::type asdf;
```

Before C++11 you couldn't have `>>` without whitespace for nested templates. It should work if you add a space:

```
vector_c<1,2,3>::sum<vector_c<3,2,1> >::type asdf;
//                                  ^
```